# how to get maximum value from array php

Tags: php, cakephp

How can I get the maximum distance from the array below? I am getting the following output when i try to print_r($data):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [distance] => 1.7 km
            [time] => 3 mins
            [distance_value] => 1720
            [time_value] => 192
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [distance] => 4.2 km
            [time] => 10 mins
            [distance_value] => 4207
            [time_value] => 587
        )

)
```

I want to echo 4.2 km because it is the max distance in my array.

```
foreach ($delivery as $key => $value) {
    if($key==0) {
        $mysource = $pickup;
    } else {
        $mysource = $delivery[$key-1];
    }
    $data[$key] = $this->GetDrivingDistance($mysource,$value);
    if(!empty($data[$key])) {
        $dist += max($data[$key]['distance']); 
    }
}
echo $dist; exit();
print_r($data); exit();
```

Comment: You want to find the max of distance only ??

Comment: Is this value 1.7 km or 1.7 ?

Comment: @all answerers, beware that `4.2 km` is a string, not float. Blind conversion gives unpredictable result! You need to convert it appropriately first. Check out my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41561604/5447994)

Comment: @Thamilan Just use `distance_value` for sorting instead. As far as I can see it contains "distance" in meters as an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get solution from below code..

```
foreach ($delivery as $key => $value) {
                        if($key==0){
                            $mysource = $pickup;
                        }else{
                            $mysource = $delivery[$key-1];
                        }
                        $data[$key] = $this->GetDrivingDistance($mysource,$value);
                        if(!empty($data[$key])){
                            $max = '-9999999 km'; //will hold max val
                            $found_item = null; //will hold item with max val;
                            foreach($data as $k=>$v)
                            {   
                                if($v['distance']>$max)
                                {
                                   $max = $v['distance'];
                                   $found_item = $v;
                                }
                            }                           
                        }
                    } 
                    $dist = $max;
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of built-in functions:

```
echo max(array_map('floatval',array_column($array, "distance")))." km";
```

---

**Explanation:**

- [`array_column`](http://php.net/array_column) - converts your array to single dimensional
- [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) - Apply float operation to the string. This is important since your string comparison compares two numbers wrongly. When float function is applied your `km` will be removed, so append later on.

**Example for string:**

11.7 is less than 4.2, because it compares first character and arranges by 1,2,3...

---

**Output:**

```
4.2 km
```

---

**Note:**
This is suitable if all values are in `km`,if it is in other units, you need a workaround too!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$array = array
(
     array
        (
            "distance" => "1.7 km",
            "time" => "3 mins",
            "distance_value" => 1720,
            "time_value" => 192,
        ),

        array
        (
            "distance" => "4.2 km",
            "time" => "10 mins",
            "distance_value" => 4207,
            "time_value" => 587,
        )
);

$distance = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $distance_data) {
    $distance[] = (float)$distance_data["distance"];
    $i++;
}
$max_distnace = max($distance);
var_dump($max_distnace);
```

Comment: Are you sure you tested your code with dynamic values?

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort the array by distance and get the required one:

```
$myArray = 
array (
    array
        (
            'distance' => '1.7 km',
            'time' => '3 mins',
            'distance_value' => 1720,
            'time_value' => 192,
        ),
    array
        (
            'distance' => '4.2 km',
            'time' => '10 mins',
            'distance_value' => 4207,
            'time_value' => 587,
        )

);

usort($myArray,function($a, $b) {
 return $b['distance_value'] - $a['distance_value'];
});

$maxDistance = $myArray[0];

echo $maxDistance['distance'];
// 4.2 km
```

Comment: if you reverse the usort comparison, you don't need array_reverse `usort($data, function ($a, $b){ return $b['distance_value'] - $a['distance_value'];});` and `echo $data[0]['distance'];`. Here is [a demo](https://eval.in/712928)

Comment: Are you sure you tested your code with dynamic values?

Comment: `distance` and `distance_value` keep the same value. Using `distance_value` to compare more stable way I think. This code is tested.

Answer (score 0):

[Thamilan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41561429/how-to-get-maximum-value-from-array-php/41561604#41561604) is the best, but as you're using CakePHP you can also use `Hash::extract()` if `array_column()` isn't available to you (*i.e.* you're using an older version of PHP) or if you need to use an array with deeper associations thanks to the `Hash` utility's path syntax:-

```
echo max(array_map('floatval', Hash::extract($array, 'distance'))) . ' km';
```

Here `Hash::extract()` is working like `array_column()` and converting your array to a single dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Sine this questions is tagged with CakePHP I though I'd give my solution using [CakePHP Collection class](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html):

```
use Cake\Collection\Collection;
(new Collection($data))->sortBy('distance_value')->first()['distance'];
```

Note that CakePHP has a utility function `collection` that can make this shorter:

```
collection($data)->sortBy('distance_value')->first()['distance']
```